# Some input files use or override a deprecated API Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using **sms_autofill: ^1.3.1** plugin from **pub.dev** 
 Everything was fine before adding this plugin.

 My **pubspec.yaml** file is as follows

```
name: example_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sms_autofill: ^1.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

after adding this plugin in blank application while debugging the app following warning is shown

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Emulator in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

flutter -doctor logs are

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

can anyone guide in removing the warning, and how to find a depreciated api used by plugin **sms_autofill**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`flutter upgrade` 
`flutter clean`
`flutter run`

If you have unexpected result when released, add this to your `app/build.gradle` file:

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'`

Comment: already have proguard-rules.pro files in build.gradle, still have the same problem. Have to initialize some vars in proguard-rules.pro for sms-autofill, looking forward for guidance

Comment: If you're able to run and build the project, I think the warning is negligible. However, you can change the dependency to sms_autofill:  without the version number so it can get the latest.

Comment: i am able to build and run the project. APMK everythings seems fine. sms_autofill is on latest version. I am bit worry about the warning about depreciated api.

Comment: I had to run my project excluding two suspected apis from pubspec.yaml and it worked without the error. I did another implementation to replace their functionality. You may need to check too.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue, I did those steps.

if you'r using API calling,
Make sure you have the Internet Permission on you android Manifest android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

if If you're using Shared Preferences plugin ,
In android\build.gradle set your dependencies to use the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
...
}
```

add following lines in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and then add these lines in android\app\build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
 release {
    shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled false
}}
```

run this command,

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

then debug your app,

```
flutter run
```

after stop the debug and building apk using the below commands,

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```

or

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-shrink
```